# Why does $\mathfrak{o}_L \cong \mathfrak{o}_K^n$ imply that $\mathfrak{o}_L/\pi_k\mathfrak{o}_L$ is a $k_K$ vector space of dimension $n$?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I'm trying to read a proof of the following proposition:

> Let $L/K$ be a finite, separable extension of a complete discretely valued field. Then $e(L/K)f(L/K)=[L:K]$.

I'm stuck on the step:

> We know $\mathfrak{o}_l \cong \mathfrak{o}_K^n$ as $\mathfrak{o}_K$ modules. So $\mathfrak{o}_L/\pi_K\mathfrak{o}_L$ is a $k_K$-vector space of dimension $n$

where $\pi_K$ is a uniformiser for $K$ (a generator of the maximal ideal of $\mathfrak{o}_K$) and $k_K=\mathfrak{o}_K/(\pi_K\mathfrak{o}_K$.

I see that the dimension must be at most $n$, since the images of the generators of $\mathfrak{o}_L$ in $\mathfrak{o}_L/\pi_K\mathfrak{o}_L$ span $\mathfrak{o}_L/\pi_K\mathfrak{o}_L$, but I don't see why they are still linearly independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the exact sequence
$$ 0 \to \pi_K\mathfrak{o}_L \cong \pi_K\mathfrak{o}_K^n \to  \mathfrak{o}_K^n \to  \mathfrak{o}_K^n/\pi_K \mathfrak{o}_K^n \to 0$$

Elements from different summands (remember that this is a *direct* sum) are linearly independent, and continues to be so after modding out by the maximal ideal. (you can't get any more relations after modding out, because we're considering the quotient as a $\mathfrak{o}_K/\pi_K\mathfrak{o}_K$-vector space, and any relation must come from the maximal ideal).